# Creating transactions with with statements in psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, transactions, psycopg2

I am trying to use [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html) to add some new columns to a table. PostgreSQL lacks a `ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS`, so I am adding each column in it's own transaction. If the column exists, there will be a python & postgres error, that's OK, I want my programme to just continue and try to add the next column. The goal is for this to be idempotent, so it can be run many times in a row.

It currently looks like this:

```
def main():
    # <snip>
    with psycopg2.connect("") as connection:
        create_columns(connection, args.table)

def create_columns(connection, table_name):
    def sql(sql):
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(sql.format(table_name=table_name))

    sql("ALTER TABLE {table_name} ADD COLUMN my_new_col numeric(10,0);")
    sql("ALTER TABLE {table_name} ADD COLUMN another_new_col INTEGER NOT NULL;")
```

However, if `my_new_col` exists, there is an exception `ProgrammingError('column "parent_osm_id" of relation "relations" already exists\n',)`, which is to be expected, but when it tried to add `another_new_col`, there is the exception `InternalError('current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block\n',)`.

The [psycogpg2 document for the `with` statement](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#with-statement) implies that the `with connection.cursor() as cursor:` will wrap that code in a transaction. This is clearly not happening. Experimentation has shown me that I need 2 levels of `with` statements, to including the `pscyopg2.connect` call, and then I get a transaction.

How can I pass a [`connection` object](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection) around and have queries run in their own transaction to allow this sort of "graceful error handling"? I would like to keep the postgres connection code separate, in a "clean architecture" style. Is this possible?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> The psycogpg2 document for the with statement implies that the with connection.cursor() as cursor: will wrap that code in a transaction.

this is actually not true it says:

> ```
> with psycopg2.connect(DSN) as conn:
>     with conn.cursor() as curs:
>        curs.execute(SQL)
> ```
>
> When a connection exits the with block, if no exception has been raised by the block, the transaction is committed. In case of exception the transaction is rolled back. In no case the connection is closed: a connection can be used in more than a with statement and each with block is effectively wrapped in a transaction.

So it's not about cursor object being handled by `with` but the connection object

Also worth noting that all resource held by cursor will be released when we leave the `with` clause

> When a cursor exits the with block it is closed, releasing any resource eventually associated with it. The state of the transaction is not affected.

So back to your code you could probably rewrite it to be more like:

```
def main():
    # <snip>
    with psycopg2.connect("") as connection:
        create_columns(connection, args.table)

def create_columns(con, table_name):
    def sql(connection, sql):
        with connection:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(sql.format(table_name=table_name))

    sql(con, "ALTER TABLE {table_name} ADD COLUMN my_new_col numeric(10,0);")
    sql(con, "ALTER TABLE {table_name} ADD COLUMN another_new_col INTEGER NOT NULL;")
```

ensuring your connection is wrapped in `with` for each query you execute, so if it fails connection context manager will revert the transaction

Comment: Using string format (sql.format) is not recommended. Use binding instead (cursor.execute(sql, {"table_name":table_name}))

Comment: Why would you do another `with connection:`?

Comment: @swade is to wrap each individual sql statement in separate transaction (the docs: `a connection can be used in more than a with statement and each with block is effectively wrapped in a transaction` )

Comment: @user3012759, would you update your answer to have the detail about _cursors_ (resources) being released at the end of the context? For your convenience (https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#with-statement): `When a cursor exits the with block it is closed, releasing any resource eventually associated with it. The state of the transaction is not affected.` Thanks.